# lINTERCAMBIAR POSICIONES IMPARES ENTRE DOS LISTAS EN PYTHON

Tags: python, visual-studio, lista

agradecería quien lo vea y amablemente me pudiera ayudar, es que no he podido sacar el siguiente `codigo`. Se supone que se deben intercambiar las posiciones pares entre dos listas que el usuario introducira. Pero no se como hacer :(. ahi ya esta la primera parte que es donde el usuario digitara los numeros en cada lista. falta intercambiar las posiciones pares.

```
lista1=[]
lista2= []
num1=int(input("Digite 8 numeros: "))
num2=int(input("Digite otros 8 numeros: "))
print(num1)
for i in range(num1):
    lista1.append(num1)
print(num2)
for i in range(num2):
    lista2.append(num2)
```

Comment: Que cosa te traba para hacerlo? Las preguntas en las que el que pregunta no demuestra ningún esfuerzo por resolver su propia duda no suelen ser bien recibidas y terminan cerradas. Si tienes código hecho (aunque no funcione) te recomiendo agregarlo a la pregunta, demostrando así tu esfuerzo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es inconsistente sobre si las posiciones a intercambiar son las pares o las impares, aquí usé las impares como dice el título

```
lista1=[]
lista2= []
print("Digite 8 numeros: ")
for i in range(8):
    lista1.append(int(input()))

print("Digite otros 8 numeros: ")
for i in range(8):
    lista2.append(int(input()))

for i in range(len(lista1)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        #Si el índice es par, la posición es impar porque el índice empieza en 0
        #Intercambiamos los valores
        aux = lista1[i]
        lista1[i] = lista2[i]
        lista2[i] = aux

print(lista1)
print(lista2)
```